# Looking for a tool to test my Ethernet connection

Tags: ethernet

I would like to build an instrument to test my Ethernet connection.  I would like it to show me if there is a 10/100 or 1000MB Link as well as the IP, subnet, and gateway addresses. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Probably already exists. Are you on Mac, PC or Linux?

Comment: It has to be a hardware, independent of any OS or manufactor!
Just a hardware you plog in to your Ethernet and get a Ip address on a display!

Comment: Please **register** your account here. If you're not registered and lost your cookie, you can't make edits or comment on the post.

Answer (score 5):

You want a pinger. There really is no need to build anything. You'll save yourself lots of time (and money) buying a tool out there that already exists. Save yourself the hassle and just buy one of these, they're ery handy tools.

[image: Pinger]

http://www.psiber.com/en/home/products/network-tester/pingerplus.html

This tool is the swiss army knife of network diagnostic tools. It will even test DHCP and DNS for you. They're pretty cheap if you can find one used or on eBay. Runs off AA bateries or you can plug it in. About the size of a medium sized house phone.

> Detects Speed and Duplex of 10/100/1000 base TX Links
>   Verifies IP Address Assignment with the DHCP Client Test
>   Tests Connectivity Across a LAN/WAN
>   Measures Packet Response Time to Determine Network Performance
>   Captures the MAC Address of an IP Address
>   Transmits Link Activation Signals for Port Identification

Answer (score 0):

[Fluke](http://www.flukenetworks.com/enterprise-network#Troubleshooting_Tools) makes a whole suite of tools that do what you are asking for.

The range from the low end [LinkRunner™ Network Multimeter](http://www.flukenetworks.com/enterprise-network/network-testing/LinkRunner-Network-Multimeter), to the very high end [OptiView® XG Network Analysis Tablet](http://www.flukenetworks.com/enterprise-network/network-monitoring/optiview-xg-network-analysis-tablet), and a lot in between.

Comment: plus Fluke, which I have, is better on your wallet when Home user VS office user case is in question.